# C++ if a class cannot synthesize a move constructor, does it mean that the move constructor is deleted?

Tags: c++, move

In code

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A& obj) = default;
};
```

since i define the copy constructor of A, A won't synthesize the move constructor. But i still can write the following code:

```
A obj;
A obj1 = std::move(obj); // call the copy constructor of A
```

But if i define class A like this

```
class A
{
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A& obj) = default;
    A(A&& obj) = delete;
};
```

the same code

```
A obj;
A obj1 = std::move(obj); // error: call to deleted constructor of A
```

then how to understand the difference between `cannot synthesize a move constructor` and `the move constructor is deleted`?

Comment: i know the answer is no, but how to understand this? thanks.

Comment: Well you explicitly deleted the move constructor which forces the compiler to give you this error. In the first scenario, as it is not deleted, the compiler will search for the default move constructor that is already defined and it will call it. Even though you didn't declare it it is still present.
Also adding ```A()=default;``` is like not putting anything, you can still define a class ```A a``` even in the case that it is not declared.

Comment: @afkid i don't agree with u, in the first scenario, since i defined the copy constructor, the compiler won't synthesize the default move constructor, copy constructor will be called when ```A obj1 = std::move(obj);```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Here you have more details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor, on how the move constructor is called. This will answer your question actually. In the first case, the implicit move constructor is not called the copy constructor is defined. The second case is explicitly deleted which means that when you want to use the universal reference, the compiler will complain.

Comment: Deleted functions will participate in overload resolution. In the second case the deleted move constructor is a better match than the copy constructor, so it is selected by overload resolution. But because it's deleted, the code will not compile. In the first case, there is no move constructor, so the copy constructor is the only viable option.

Comment: thanks, added info `The deleted implicitly-declared move constructor is ignored by overload resolution (otherwise it would prevent copy-initialization from rvalue)' (en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)